# import a dict from a different file ina different directory in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dict defined in a file in a separate directory. Now, to import such a dict in a different file, have declared the dict as global, then in other file have done like this:

import bin.postprocess-exe import ret   P.S: the path is bin/postprocess-exe.py where the dict(ret) is declared.

When I am giving this, I am getting error:
from bin.postprocess-exe import ret_val
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Can somebody please help.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can't have a module named `postprocess-exe`. That is invalid. You could rename it to `postprocess_exe`...

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't know it, however when I renamed the file, it breaks something else, neverthless, very helpful....thanks a lot